# base_convert 10 to 26 characters length

Tags: php, base-conversion

I want to create a string with the first 4 chars to be the user id and the the 4 last chars the ref id.

I use `base_convert()` to convert the IDs to URL-friendly strings, one for the user id and one for the ref id and then I add them together to make the URL GET variable.

I need to know alway that the 4 first characters is user ID and last four is the reference ID.

From which decimal number the string (26) has 4 characters and where ends?

Comment: Please share the code you have tried when posting to Stack Overflow.

Comment: i am not using some code except base_convert('aaaa',26,10) which i tried last to find out if it is the first decimal which is not. the first is '0000' but the base_convert('0000',26,10) returns 0

Comment: base_convert is for numbers, not strings.  Maybe you mean base64_encode.  You can then use base64_decode to get the values afterwards.

Comment: the base_convert('aaaa',26,10) returns 7030 and the base_covert(7030,10,26) returns aaaa . It is for strings

Comment: No! base_convert() is only for numbers.  "aaaa" just happens to be a valid hex number.

Answer (score 0):

As addressed in question comments, you'll need to use base64_encode()/base64_decode(), or any other encoding you wish.

However unless you are limiting the inputs there is no guarantee you will always get a 4 character string once you encode.  In the case of base64_encode() it almost never will be 4 chars.

Therefore you will need to set a delimiter.  Perhaps use "-" between the encoded user id and the encoded ref id.  You then just need to explode on the "-" and decode the two values.

Comment: Yes this is an option. Thank you